# Can you overwrite a variable that is defined by the result of a function without clearing first in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, python-2.7, overwrite

So, I was wondering if there was a way to clear and overwrite/rewrite a variable in one step without having to clear it before hand.

This is what I have for example:

```
def rate(t,w):
    return (t + cos(t))

sum = 0
for i in range(k):
    sum += rate(t+h*i,w)

print sum
```

but then if I want to reuse this function in a different manner, I have to clear the "sum" variable first. I want to get rid of that step, if possible.

```
sum = 0                   # I want to combine this step
sum = rate(t,w)/2         # and this one.
for i in range(1,k):
    sum += rate(t+h*i,w)

print sum
```

Is this possible? (btw, all this code would be in the same document.)

Comment: First, don't name a variable `sum` since it shadows the [Python builtin function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) of the same name.

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to clear the variable in the second example. Delete the line, and see that the program still works.

In Python the assignment (`=`) operator binds names to objects:

```
a = 2 * 4
```

In this line the computation `2 * 4` creates an `int` object with the value 8. The `=` operator then binds it to the name `a`. You can reuse the name as many times as you want:

```
a = "hello"
```

The name `a` is now bound to a `str` object with the value "hello". The `int` from the previous line of code will be deleted automatically when it is no longer used.

This concept of "binding names to objects" leads to subtle differences in behavior between Python and other languages, which treat variables as little "buckets" that you can fill with values.

Comment: I meant to write that in the code blocks, so I apologize. In the rate function within the loop, I implement like so: rate(ti + h*i,w) , where "ti" is a defined, time_initial value. I have a "tf" (time_final) defined in my program as well.

Comment: I expanded my answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to set it to 0 because by having the "sum =", it redefines the variable with no info kept from the last assignment.

Hint: use another variable name other than sum, Python already uses it...